# Best way to use Sanitize in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, sql-injection, cakephp-2.3

i want to save and show that string as it is in page, but did not want to execute on page load.

```
<input type="text" value="Hello">

Hi my name is  <script>alert('Hello');</script>

<?php ehco "sfsdfsdfds";?>
```

i am using Sanitize::clean, after save it will encode html tag, but on view i want it same as original text.

i try all  Sanitize methode.. but not getting what i need

Answer (score 0):

All output should be passed through the h() function which is a shortcut for [htmpspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). This will show the text as it is in HTML entities.